# What system or sourcebooks should I use to run a pre Roman, Celtic Britain campaign?

Tags: game-recommendation, campaign-development

Someone I know, wants to run a campaign in Celtic Britain. He normally uses Pathfinder but is looking for something more appropriate to the background.

Comment: Could you give a bit more information? What you feel are the key bits of the setting, and maybe what kind of feel you're going for with the campaign? What you see as the shortcomings of Pathfinder in this scenario?

Comment: Yes, what are you trying to accomplish? Is this about individual adventurers? Or clans? Or kingdoms? What's at stake in this game?

Comment: Sorry, I hope to get more from my friend soon.

Comment: I will comment here once I know the outcome from my friend but I think @Viktor Haag has the best answer.

Comment: It's been a long time but I seem to remember a very enjoyable game for just this sort of setting, using the old RuneQuest ruleset (not sure which edition I'm afraid.

Comment: Please give us *far* more details about what you want from the system and what aspects of the setting you want to explore.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect that the answer depends entirely upon what tone you want to have in your game. If you want something that's truer to mythical source references, then you should look at [GURPS Celtic Myth](http://www.sjgames.com/gurps/books/celtic/) as a sourcebook for either GURPS or some other rules-system (Ken and [Jo Walton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jo_Walton) wrote the book, and Jo Walton knows her some Celtic myth).

If you want "King Arthur and the Celts", then you can use [Pendragon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendragon_%28role-playing_game%29) along with the supplements Pagan Shore for Ireland and Savage Mountains for Wales -- except of course that King Arthur is post-Roman and that can mean a lot. Still might have some useful resources, but the game as written is most definitely post-Roman.

If you want something less "realistic", then you can look for the RPG (now out of print) that Mongoose published based on the 2000AD comic, Sláine, called [Sláine: The Role Playing Game of Celtic Heroes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slaine_-_The_Roleplaying_Game_of_Celtic_Heroes). It's crazy over-the-top, but full of flavour, and has a host of sourcebooks released for it. Unfortunately, it's likely that it'll be hard to track down because it was a licensed property, now I believe out of print, so PDFs are not (afaik) available: you'd have to hit the used market.

Comment: Pendragon seconded. *Sláine, it's crazy over-the-top* - just like the comic.

Comment: +1 for **GURPS Celtic Myth**.  As a source for the region, culture, etc., it would be a HUGE boost.  The chapter on characters could fairly easily be converted to other systems (he says with a straight face).  Only the chapter on magic is likely to be "not useful" - and even then, I'm sure you can salvage a good chunk of it as "flavor" anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There is a free [Mythic Ireland](http://www.savageheroes.com/original.htm) setting PDF by John Briquelet ([direct link](http://www.savageheroes.com/conversions/Mythic%20Ireland.pdf)) that contains a lot of useful flavour and cultural detail, assuming you want some mythical and magic touches to your pre-Roman Celts. Even if not, the feeling of the culture – especially the details of honour, the political organisation of the Celts, the role of Druids and the law – is conveyed impressively well and can be used separately from the more mythic beliefs and truths of the setting. It also gives you a solid grounding in what they believed was true, even if it's not actually true in your own Celtic setting.

The PDF happens to be for *Savage Worlds*, but like most sourcebooks for multi-genre systems, it's valuable regardless of what system you're using.

Comment: Interestingly he was thinking about Savage Worlds, I will pass this on, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seams that there is a Pathfinder sourcebook in developement called **Keld: an Iron Age Celtic** [ENworld: Iron Age Celtic setting ideas...](http://www.enworld.org/forum/pathfinder-rpg-discussion/278433-iron-age-celtic-setting-ideas.html)